# Selenium IDE export working strangely with Test::Unit and Ruby

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, selenium

I'm new to **Selenium** and I think I got **Selenium IDE** to work quite nicely, but something strange is happening (perhaps a bug) when I export **Selenium IDE (2.5.0)** Test Case to a **Ruby Test::Unit / WebDriver** test. My test works fine when I run it from **Selenium IDE**, but after I **exported** it to **Ruby** the following code doesn't work:

```
verify { assert_match /.*Welcome/, @driver.find_element(:xpath, "//title").text }
```

On Selenium IDE the same test is defined as:

Command: `verifyText`

Target: `//title`

Value: `regexp:.*Welcome`

and it works fine (attached screenshot) [image]

Below is the **Test::Unit** error message for: `verify { assert_match /.*Welcome/, @driver.find_element(:xpath, "//title").text }` So there is some kind of problem with the `RegEx` I guess. The *title* should end with the word 'Welcome'.

```
jyrki@ubu:~/rails_projects/p3$ rake test test/selenium/employer_signup_ruby2_test.rb 
Loaded suite /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/rake
Started
F
===============================================================================
Failure:
test_employer_signup_ruby2(EmployerSignupRuby2)
/home/jyrki/rails_projects/p3/test/selenium/employer_signup_ruby2_test.rb:17:in `teardown'
<[]> expected but was
<[#<Test::Unit::AssertionFailedError: <""> expected to be =~
</.*Welcome/>.>]>

diff:
+ [#<Test::Unit::AssertionFailedError: <""> expected to be =~
? [              ]
? </.*Welcome/>.> 
===============================================================================


Finished in 12.747676835 seconds.

1 tests, 2 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications
100% passed

0.08 tests/s, 0.16 assertions/s
Run options: --seed 25544

# Running tests:



Finished tests in 0.003802s, 0.0000 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Below is the code that works apart from the one line of the code:

```
require "json"
require "selenium-webdriver"
gem "test-unit" #?
require "test/unit"

class EmployerSignupRuby2 < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def setup
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    @base_url = "http://0.0.0.0:3000/"
    @accept_next_alert = true
    @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
    @verification_errors = []
  end

  def teardown
    @driver.quit
    assert_equal [], @verification_errors
  end

  def test_employer_signup_ruby2
    @driver.get(@base_url + "/employer_signup")
    @driver.find_element(:id, "employer_first_name").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "employer_first_name").send_keys "tester"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "employer_last_name").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "employer_last_name").send_keys "login-tester"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "employer_email").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "employer_email").send_keys "tester012345678901@test.com"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "employer_password").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "employer_password").send_keys "foobar"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "employer_password_confirmation").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "employer_password_confirmation").send_keys "foobar"
    @driver.find_element(:name, "commit").click
    verify { assert_match /.*Welcome/, @driver.find_element(:xpath, "//title").text }
  end

  def element_present?(how, what)
    @driver.find_element(how, what)
    #${receiver}.find_element(how, what)
    true
  rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
    false
  end

  def alert_present?()
    @driver.find_element(how, what)
    #${receiver}.switch_to.alert
    true
  rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoAlertPresentError
    false
  end

  def verify(&blk)
    yield
  rescue Test::Unit::AssertionFailedError => ex
    @verification_errors << ex
  end

  def close_alert_and_get_its_text(how, what)
    alert = @driver.switch_to().alert()
    #alert = ${receiver}.switch_to().alert()
    alert_text = alert.text
    if (@accept_next_alert) then
      alert.accept()
    else
      alert.dismiss()
    end
    alert_text
  ensure
    @accept_next_alert = true
  end
end
```

Actually, I can get the test to work (sort of) when I replace the one line of code with this:

```
verify { assert @driver.find_element(:xpath, '//title[contains(.,"Welcome")]') } #works!!
```

However if the “Welcome” text is missing (=test is failing), then the fix will remain in a loop indefinitely and I have interrupt (Ctrl + C) the test. So far this is the best fix I have found. If you know a better fix, please let me know, thanks :-)

My Gemfile has the following rails/selenium/test versions:

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.41.0' #this is the latest version
gem  'test-unit', '2.5.5'
gem 'rake', '10.2.2'
```

--

```
$ bundle show json
The gem json has been deleted. It was installed at:
/home/jyrki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/json-1.8.1
```

Ruby 2.1.0

In addition, the export creates ruby code: `${receiver}.find_element(how, what)` that doesn't work; so I needed to change it to `@driver.find_element(how, what)` to make it work.

Also, export creates a gem statement in addition to require statement for test-unit (lines 3-4):

```
gem "test-unit" #?
require "test/unit"
```

I might ask about this issue from [Selenium Users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/selenium-users) Google Group as well

Btw, do you know if Selenium IDE exports work better with RSpec than Test::Unit?